# How to add EventListener on CustomEvent in Vaadin14 WebComponent

Tags: typescript, vaadin, web-component, stenciljs

I want to create a web component with [StencilJs](https://stenciljs.com/) and I use the [MultiSelectListBox](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-list-box/html-api/elements/Vaadin.ListBoxElement) components of Vaadin 14.
I try to bind a function to the CustomEvent ***selected-values-changed***, but I don't know how it works.

I tried that:

```
import '@vaadin/vaadin-list-box'
...
<vaadin-list-box onSelectedValuesChange={this.foo} multiple>
...
</vaadin-list-box>
```

Comment: not sure but maybe it's just a typo? `onSelectedValuesChanged` with a `d` at the end...

Comment: Otherwise you could try `document.querySelector('vaadin-list-box').addEventListener('selected-values-changed', console.log)`?

Comment: I finally use the `addEventListener` in `componentDidLoad()` and its work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the *StencilJs* library, so not sure is the solution below applicable directly, but in polymer template you could do something like this :

```js
ready() {
     super.ready();
     var divValue=this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#output");
     this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#vlb").addEventListener('selected-values-changed', function(event) {
            console.log(this.selectedValues);
            divValue.innerText=this.selectedValues + " First Item: " + 
                this.items[this.selectedValues[0]].value;
        });
```

And the complete example is :

```js
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-list-box/vaadin-list-box.js';

/**
 * `listbox-view`
 *
 * ListboxView element.
 *
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class ListboxView extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
            <style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                }
            </style>
   <div>
    <vaadin-list-box id="vlb" multiple>
      <b>Register to Language Courses</b>
      <vaadin-item>Finnish</vaadin-item>
      <vaadin-item>Swedish</vaadin-item>
      <hr>
      <vaadin-item disabled>Spanish (not available)</vaadin-item>
      <vaadin-item>English</vaadin-item>
   </vaadin-list-box>
   <div id="output">Selected value:</div>
</div>
        `;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'listbox-view';
    }

    ready() {
        super.ready();
        var divValue=this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#output");
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#vlb").addEventListener('selected-values-changed', function(event) {
            console.log(this.selectedValues);
            divValue.innerText=this.selectedValues + " First Item: " + this.items[this.selectedValues[0]].value;
        });
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(ListboxView.is, ListboxView);
```

**Notes**:

The [property `selectedValues`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-list-box/html-api/elements/Vaadin.ListBoxElement) returns an array of indexes, so you would need to extract the names yourself, if you need them.

Comment: Thank you, but i bind the CustomEvent in  the `componentDidLoad` lifecyle method.